# Painkillers increasing on re-spawning in Max Payne 3 ..?

Tags: max-payne-3

I found that after each time Max Payne is killed and when he is re-spawned, the amount of painkillers gets added by one which make the game a little easier. Is it a bug or is it that way that the game is designed.

Comment: Pretty sure it's by design. It also may depend on what difficulty level you are playing at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is designed in the game depending on which difficulty you are playing on.

> **Easy and Medium settings feature dynamic difficulty which provides access to extra painkillers to help you pass particular parts of the game if you've died repeatedly.** On Easy and Medium settings, when you die at a checkpoint, you restart the checkpoint with at least one full magazine of ammo in each gun (except grenade launchers) and the number of painkillers that you started with. **For every three times you die at a checkpoint, you get one extra painkiller.** So if you started a checkpoint with 2 painkillers, and died 3 times, on each subsequent retry of that checkpoint, you'd start with 3 painkillers.  If you died 3 more times (6 total), you'd start with 4 painkillers on each subsequent restart.  On Easy and Medium, this can continue until you are respawning with a full 9 painkillers.

[Rockstar Source](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/34161/rockstar-game-tips-difficulty-settings-getting-started-in-max-pa.html)